# Could not reserve enough space for object heap liferay tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, virtual

When I am running i am getting following exception repeatedly each time i try to run the program.

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Liferay v6.1 CE Server
>   (Tomcat 7) at localhost are already in use. The server may already be
>   running in another process, or a system process may be using the port.
>   To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change
>   the port number(s).

I tired to increase my virtual memory(page size) and ram size. But it not workinge
Currently, I used win 7 64 bit, java jdk, jre 64 bit. I tried to change JDK,JRE (32 bit). However, the result is the same. :(

> Can any one tell me how can i eliminate this error.

Comment: The message clearly says it all. The ports are in use. Find and kill the process using the ports.

Answer (score 0):

Either figure out which other program uses the ports that Liferay/Tomcat would like to use out of the box (most likely: 8080) and terminate it.

Or, in your liferay installation, locate the file `tomcat-[version]/conf/server.xml`, edit it with your favourite text editor and locate all the port instructions and change them to unused values - e.g. change "8080" to "9090", "8009" to "9009" and "8005" to "9005" (or anything else, the point is to find ports that are not yet in use)

After this, assumed that you made the choices I named above, connect to your Liferay installation at `http://localhost:9090/` and have fun.

Comment: I tried as per your suggestions, But the result is the same as before

Comment: You either didn't change *all* ports declared in server.xml or you changed them to other ports that were also busy if you got *the same* result as before. You might also be starting Liferay/tomcat multiple times - it can run only once. Execute `shutdown.bat` or `shutdown.sh` before you startup a new instance. Clearly the headline of your question is wrong, because the error message has nothing to do with memory settings