# i'm trying to configuring liferay with mysql but i have a oracle give me this wrong results

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, liferay-7

I'm trying to configure Liferay 7 with MySQL but when I try to make the connection between the server give me these errors where I've done wrong?

30-Aug-2019 15:09:35.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [963] milliseconds
    Loading jar:file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.0-ga1/tomcat-9.0.17/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/user/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.0-ga1/tomcat-9.0.17/lib/ext/com.liferay.petra.reflect.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    30-Aug-2019 15:09:38.779 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener]
     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil.(ReflectionUtil.java:160)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:479)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4604)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2416)
        at com.liferay.petra.reflect.ReflectionUtil.(ReflectionUtil.java:155)
        ... 48 more

```
30-Aug-2019 15:09:38.781 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
30-Aug-2019 15:09:38.781 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
30-Aug-2019 15:09:39.103 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
30-Aug-2019 15:09:39.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [3,549] milliseconds
30-Aug-2019 15:09:39.289 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Failed to create server shutdown socket on address [localhost] and port [8005] (base port [8005] and offset [0])
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:386)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:582)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:668)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

Comment: The port is already in use, you need to see who is using that port and kill it

Comment: i,ve tried to see if the 8005 port is occuped but don't result by using netstat -anb

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237096/exception-when-i-try-to-run-a-liferay-portlet-on-my-tomcat-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594033/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-liferay-tomcat